# How to use DrawString outside the form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i am wondering how to use DrawString outside the form so I am can see the coordinates of my mouse even when the form is closed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: just *what* are you hoping to draw the mouse position on?  `Console.WriteLine` might work for debug purposes.

Comment: You'll still need a window to draw on. Trying to draw on the screen is pretty much nothing but a PITA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342570/draw-on-screen-with-gdi-or-gdi-similar-to-inspect  You should just create a small form to track the information. Forms can be borderless and transparent to mimic the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need a form to draw on. The trick is to make everything about the form except your text invisible. This can be done by using the forms `Backcolor` and `TransparencyKey` properties. Take this form as an example.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents timer As New Timer With {.Interval = 500}
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BackColor = Color.Pink
        Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Pink
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
        Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
            g.Clear(Color.Pink)
            g.DrawString(MousePosition.ToString, New Font("Arial", 20), Brushes.Red, New PointF(10, 10))
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Every color on the form that has the `TransparencyKey` color is transparent. This makes only the text you draw on the form visible. Set the `TopMost` property to keep the form from dropping behind other applications.